# When i attempt to @Autowired give a an Error like this why this happened?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#19d7685' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19d7685': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#19d7685' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19d7685': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#19d7685' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19d7685': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19d7685': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:662)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
[2019-08-13 10:10:02,789] Artifact Spring-POS-API:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-08-13 10:10:02,792] Artifact Spring-POS-API:war exploded: Deploy took 39,451 milliseconds
```

**WebConfig class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.springpos")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    static{
        System.out.println("WebConfig.static initializer");
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("springpos");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.springpos"/>-->
    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven/>-->
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="springpos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


    <class>com.springpos.entity.CustomerEntity</class>
    <class>com.springpos.entity.ItemEntity</class>
    <class>com.springpos.entity.OrderEntity</class>
    <class>com.springpos.entity.OrderDetailEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringPOS?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Controller.class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public ResponseEntity getAllCustomers()  {
        List<CustomerDTO> allCustomers = null;
        try {
            allCustomers = customerService.getAllCustomers();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception = " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(allCustomers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

**Service interface**

```
public interface CustomerService {

    public CustomerDTO addCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO);

    public CustomerDTO updateCustomer(String id, CustomerDTO customerDTO);

    public CustomerDTO deleteCustomer(String id);

    public CustomerDTO searchCustomer(String id);

    public List<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomers();
}
```

**ServiceImpl.class**

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Override
    public List<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomers()  {
        List<CustomerEntity> customerList = customerRepo.findAll();
        System.out.println("customerList = " + customerList);
        ArrayList<CustomerDTO> dto = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CustomerEntity cus : customerList) {

            dto.add(new CustomerDTO(cus.getCustomerId(),
                    cus.getCustomerName(),
                    cus.getCustomerAddress(),
                    cus.getCustomerTele(),
                    cus.getCustomerEmail()
            ));
        }
        return dto;
    }
    @Override
    public CustomerDTO addCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO)  {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerDTO updateCustomer(String id, CustomerDTO customerDTO)  {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerDTO deleteCustomer(String id)  {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerDTO searchCustomer(String id)  {
        return null;
    }


}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity(name="Customer")
public class CustomerEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;
    private String customerTele;
    private String customerEmail;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomerEntity() {
    }

    public CustomerEntity(String customerId, String customerName, String customerAddress, String customerTele, String customerEmail) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
        this.customerTele = customerTele;
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }

    public String getCustomerTele() {
        return customerTele;
    }

    public void setCustomerTele(String customerTele) {
        this.customerTele = customerTele;
    }

    public String getCustomerEmail() {
        return customerEmail;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail) {
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }

    public List<OrderEntity> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<OrderEntity> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerEntity{" +
                "customerId='" + customerId + '\'' +
                ", customerName='" + customerName + '\'' +
                ", customerAddress='" + customerAddress + '\'' +
                ", customerTele='" + customerTele + '\'' +
                ", customerEmail='" + customerEmail + '\'' +
                ", orders=" + orders +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**CustomerRepo interface**

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity ,String> {

}
```

I am using `JpaRepository<>` to do the implementation in database operations.
when I used `@Autowired` in the startup of the application give me above Error.
Also, I am a new developer to `spring`.I checked all occurrences But in vain.
Find help in advance Thanks you.

Comment: In **ServiceImpl.class** try `@component` instead of `@service`. Ideally this is not a solution , both it should work , but give a try

Comment: no, sir that not working yet that error occurs

Comment: Show us CustomerRepo.. also do you define SharedEntityManagerCreator anywhere?

Comment: You might new the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation

Comment: I uploaded question with CustomerRepo.

Comment: When I put that ```@EnableJpaRepositories``` ? is that put in WebConfig class?

Comment: in @ComponentScan("com.springpos") use @ComponentScan("com.springpos.*") try this in xml and WebConfig class

Comment: The error comes up yet , sir

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find a bean named "entityManagerFactory". In your config class you have a `getEntityManagerFactoryBean` but this becomes a bean named `getEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of `entityManagerFactory`.

Try renaming the method to `entityManagerFactory()` like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("springpos");
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Also, you should let Spring inject the EMF into the transactionManager by supplying it as a method parameter:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Apologies. Spring doesn't even strip out the `get` prefix: ["By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html). Just name the method what you need the bean name to be.

Comment: Formatting came out all wrong in my comment, so I added code examples to my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

the error message tells you, that you dont have a bean named `entityManagerFactory`

your method

```
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("springpos");
    return factoryBean;
}
```

returns a `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

i think you need something like

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("springpos");
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

if you also need the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` you could change your code to

```
@Bean("entityManagerFactoryBean")
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("springpos");
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean("entityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactoryBean(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryBean") final LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean) {
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

`@Bean("[bean-id]")` is equivalent to `id`-property in xml-configuration and identifies a special bean

`@Qualifier("[bean-id]")` is equivalent to `ref`-property in xml-configuration and tells spring to use the bean with the given identifier

as far as i know, autowiring by type is springs default and you dont have to provide an identifier. but you must use an identifier if you want to provide multiple `javax.sql.DataSource`s, for example